# Cannot set a RobotFramework dictionary

Tags: robotframework

I wrote this simple minimal script to show how I suffer:

main.robot

```
Library  Collections
Library          BuiltIn
Library          String


*** Variables ***
&{info}    Create Dictionary


*** Test Cases ***
Case_00_Initialization
    Log     Hello 1     WARN
    Set To Dictionary    ${info}   field1=A sample string
    Log     Hello 2     WARN
```

Running this code by

```
python -m robot -L TRACE --NoStatusRC main.robot
```

Gives me errors:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\test\main.robot' on line 7: Setting variable '&{info}' failed: Invalid dictionary variable item 'Create Dictionary'. Items must use 'name=value' syntax or be dictionary variables themselves.
==============================================================================
Main
==============================================================================
[ WARN ] Hello 1
Case_00_Initialization                                                | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Set To Dictionary' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Main                                                                  | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\test\output.xml
Log:     C:\test\log.html
Report:  C:\test\report.html
```

The application is supposed to set a variable `info` in the initialization and it will be used in the next test cases. I do not want to use `Set Global Variable` however.

Please note that this is a minimal working example, do not suggest to set `field1` at `Variables` section. It is not possible. Even that one will not solve the problem of `No keyword with name 'Set To Dictionary' found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found what is wrong. I was missing the line for `*** Settings ***` I couldn't imagine that it does matter. Shame that RF does not have many full examples online.

This is the working code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections


*** Variables ***
&{info}


*** Test Cases ***
Case_00_Initialization
    Log     Hello 1     WARN
    Set To Dictionary    ${info}   field1=A sample string
    Log     Hello 2     WARN
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Variables section you cannot use keywords - and this is exactly what you did with the `Create Dictionary` there.
You can add some key:values to it (like "field" , but you don't allow us that ;), or - you can initialize it to be an empty dictionary (e.g. like `{}` in python). The later is done by passing the special value `&{Empty}`:

```
*** Variables ***
&{info}    &{Empty}
```

Comment: Thanks Todor, the main issue is the second error `No keyword with name 'Set To Dictionary' found.` which still persists.